# jQuery animate function is resetting scroll when called second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement, where I have to scroll to an element with particular class in a `DIV`. This should happen on user click.
For this I choose to use jQuery's `animate()` function. This is working fine.

It works fine for first time, however when user click on button again it resets the scroll position. And works well again on third time....

I know this is happening because the `offest` of the element to which I need scroll is getting changed after scroll.

Here is my sample code:
HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-div">
        <ul>
            <li>1. The Shawshank Redemption (1994)  9.2</li>
            <li>2. The Godfather (1972)     9.2</li>
            <li>3. The Godfather: Part II (1974)    9.0</li>
            <li>4. The Dark Knight (2008)   8.9</li>
            <li>5. 12 Angry Men (1957)  8.9</li>
            <li>6. Schindler's List (1993)  8.9</li>
            <li>7. Pulp Fiction (1994)  8.9</li>
            <li>8. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)     8.9</li>
            <li>9. The Good, the Bad and the Ugly (1966)    8.8</li>
            <li>10. Fight Club (1999)   8.8</li>
            <li>11. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)    8.8</li>
            <li>12. Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980)   8.7</li>
            <li>13. Forrest Gump (1994)     8.7</li>
            <li>14. Inception (2010)    8.7</li>
            <li>15. The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)    8.7</li>
            <li>16. One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)  8.7</li>
            <li>17. Goodfellas (1990)   8.7</li>
            <li>18. The Matrix (1999)   8.7</li>
            <li>19. Seven Samurai (1954)    8.6</li>
            <li>20. Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)   8.6</li>
            <li>21. City of God (2002)  8.6</li>
            <li class="seven" style="color:red;">22. Se7en (1995)   8.6</li>
            <li>23. La La Land (2016)   8.6</li>
            <li>24. The Silence of the Lambs (1991)     8.6</li>
            <li>25. It's a Wonderful Life (1946)    8.6</li>
            <li>26. The Usual Suspects (1995)   8.6</li>
            <li>27. Life Is Beautiful (1997)    8.6</li>
            <li>28. Léon: The Professional (1994)   8.5</li>
            <li>29. Spirited Away (2001)    8.5</li>
            <li>30. Saving Private Ryan (1998)  8.5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Scroll to Seven" onclick="scrollToSeven()" />
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-div{
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

Java Script:

```
function scrollToSeven(){
  $(".scroll-div").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.seven').offset().top - $('.scroll-div').offset().top
  }, 5);
}
```

This code is deployed at [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kishorp/psjzgx2g/) you can see the demo.

When you click on `Scroll to Seven` button for first time it scrolls to the element perfectly. If you click again it resets back.
How can I make it work for multiple clicks?
Please help if anyone faced same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated version:

```
function scrollToSeven(){
    $(".scroll-div").animate({
        scrollTop:  $(".scroll-div").scrollTop() + $('.seven').offset().top
    }, 5);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/psjzgx2g/3/

Comment: You used the offset-top of the scrollable-div, but that never changes. You need to use the scroll-top of the scrollable-div, which changes when you scroll.

Now you can make this function like "scrollTo(classname)" to make it work for all the others too. Good luck!

Comment: Great! Thanks mate.